# In PHP what does it mean by a function being binary-safe?

Tags: php

In `PHP` what does it mean by a function being **`binary-safe`** ?

What makes them special and where are they typically used ?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

It means the function will work correctly when you pass it arbitrary binary data (i.e. strings containing non-ASCII bytes and/or null bytes).

For example, a non-binary-safe function might be based on a C function which expects null-terminated strings, so if the string contains a null character, the function would ignore anything after it.

This is relevant because PHP does not cleanly separate string and binary data.

Comment: Does that mean that binary safe strings only contain "characters" of length 1 byte?

Comment: @CharlieParker: No, you got that backwards. Binary safety is a property of *functions* which  means they process *any* string correctly. The converse would be a string that contains only ASCII characters *and* no null characters - such a string should be processed correctly by any function.

Comment: maybe I got confused because I was reading the redis protocol for "bulk strings" and it said that they represent a "single binary binary safe" string. I think I understand your post correctly now. However, does it makes sense to say that a string is "binary safe" (as in the example I provided)?

Answer (score 101):

The other users already mentioned what `binary safe` means in general.

In PHP, the meaning is more specific, referring only to what Michael gives as an example.

All strings in PHP have a length associated, which are the number of bytes that compose it. When a function manipulates a string, it can either:

1. Rely on that length meta-data.
2. Rely on the string being null-terminated, i.e., that after the data that is actually part of the string, a byte with value `0` will appear.

It's also true that all string PHP variables manipulated by the engine are also null-terminated. The problem with functions that rely on 2., is that, if the string itself contains a byte with value `0`, the function that's manipulating it will think the string has ended at that point and will ignore everything after that.

For instance, if PHP's `strlen` function worked like C standard library `strlen`, the result here would be wrong:

```
$str = "abc\x00abc";
echo strlen($str); //gives 7, not 3!
```

Comment: In my test in PHP 7.0, strlen() function is a binary safe function.

Comment: @Artefacto : Are you saying that the built-in PHP function `strlen()` is a **binary-safe** function? I'm confirming from you because on the **PHP Manual** page for the function `strlen()` it's not been mentioned that whether it's a **binary-safe** function or a **non-binary safe** function. This only missing thing from the **PHP Manual** is creating the confusion in my mind so I want to confirm it from you. I'm keenly looking forward to your reply. Thank You.

Comment: @PHPLover yes strlen() is binary safe. run `php -r 'var_dump("\x00\x00\x00");'` to verify, but php's strlen has been binary safe for a **very** long time, since at least php 4.x  (that said, there is an abomination called "mb_overload", but lets just pretend that doesn't exist - https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php )

Answer (score 66):

***More examples:***

```
<?php

    $string1 = "Hello";
    $string2 = "Hello\x00World";

    // This function is NOT ! binary safe
    echo strcoll($string1, $string2); // gives 0, strings are equal.

    // This function is binary safe
    echo strcmp($string1, $string2); // gives <0, $string1 is less than $string2.

?>
```

`\x` indicates hexadecimal notation. See: [PHP strings](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

```
0x00 = NULL
0x04 = EOT (End of transmission)
```

[ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see ASCII char list

Comment: Just to make sure I understood, then `Hello\r\nWORLD` should not be the same as `Hello` if the function is binary safe, right?

Comment: Also, how is such a function implemented? Is there a regular expression that checks that its binary safe or does it use a different method?

Comment: @Subscriberius : Is the built in function `strlen()` **binary-safe**?

Comment: @PHPNut as the documentation points out `strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.`
So if you want to get the number of characters for any given string, use `mb_strlen` instead.