# Is safe to use password_hash with unicode characters?

Tags: php

Is safe to use `password_hash` with unicode characters like following or there are incompatibility problems?

```
<?php
$hash = password_hash("漢字", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
?>
```

Comment: Hashes work against bytes, not against characters; so perfectly safe and no compatibility issues

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you a lot.

Comment: @MarkBaker maybe turn your comment into an answer then.

Answer (score 4):

The hashing algorithms themselves work on bytes, so they are unicode safe, as Mark commented.  The only issue might be PHP's handling of unicode strings, i.e. are the password hashing functions [binary-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264514/in-php-what-does-it-mean-by-a-function-being-binary-safe)?  Let's test it and find out:

```
<?php

$pass = 0;
$fail = 0;

# Generate 100 random unicode passwords
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $password = '';
    for ($p = 0; $p < 10; $p++) {
        $password .= mt_rand(0xa1, 0xffff);
    }

    # Test password hashing
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        $pass++;
    } else {
        $fail++;
    }
}

echo "Pass: $pass\nFail: $fail\n";
```

Result:

```
Pass: 100
Fail: 0
```

The answer to your question is **yes**, it's safe.