# In PHP what does it mean by a binary safe string comparison?

Tags: php, string, string-comparison

Some examples of PHP functions that contain this description are strcmp () and strcasecmp (), how do they work internally? How does this binary comparison work?
I have not been able to understand why these functions return -1, 0 and 1 (or <0, 0 and >0)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the question what "binary safe" mean or is it why does the comparison return -1 ,0 and 1 ?

Comment: @apokryfos I mean "binary safe string comparison", and I think this operation results in that -1, 0 and 1 (or <0, 0 and  >0) but I can't figure out how it works.

Comment: Binary safe is not related with the -1 ,0 and 1 values of the comparison result. You can have a binary safe operation that is not a comparison and you can have a comparison which is not binary-safe but still returns -1, 0 and 1.

Comment: I understand that a binary safe string comparison operation is not necessarily related to -1, 0 and -1 (or else <0, 0 and> 0 according to the PHP documentation of these functions) but what I am dealing with to understand is how these functions work internally.

Comment: Is the answer below from the docs not sufficient to explain that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In PHP what does it mean by a function being binary-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264514/in-php-what-does-it-mean-by-a-function-being-binary-safe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If the two strings have identical BEGINNING parts, they are truncated from both strings.
2. The resulting strings are compared with two possible outcomes:

- if one of the resulting strings is an empty string, then the length of the non-empty string is returned (the sign depending on the order in which you pass the arguments to the function)
- in any other case just the numerical values of the FIRST characters are compared. The result is +1 or -1 no matter how big is the difference between the numerical values.

[source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php#123554)

Comment: It took me a little to understand how it works, I see that the key is the first character. Thanks for sharing the link, it helped me a lot. Regards

Comment: This example also helps a lot: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php#110975