# Can CRYPT_BLOWFISH encrypt all UTF-8 characters?

Tags: php, utf-8, bcrypt

I have a password field on my signup form, which is encrypted by the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm using a PHP built in function like this:

```
$hashed_password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

before it is sent to the database.

Now, I am wondering if CRYPT_BLOWFISH can encrypt all UTF-8 characters, not just the basic ASCII ones.

Now you might say to me, "But, why don't you test it out yourself?" Well, I am working on the rest of the PHP validation script, so I can't do it myself. If anyone is willing to test it out and give me the answer, go for it! All help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: better explanation: I use php for validation, and I am still working on the validation part (i.e, still writing code). In my code I use the statement "$hashed_password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT)", and send that value to the database. I am wondering if bcrypt can encrypt characters outside the English language (for example Chinese characters).

Comment: I included your comment in your question. Still think it's weird to ask us to test this for you.

Comment: Sorry, should've worded it a little differently. I just wanted someone to provide the answer.

Comment: I understand, anyway, you've got your answer in the end.

Comment: The bcrypt algorithm specifies that password strings should be UTF-8 encoded, and *do* include the null terminator, before being truncted to 72-bytes and hashed. So, yes, it can handle Unicode. Also note that SASL says your password unicode string should be cleaned up a bit first a) normalized to NFKC form, b) replace all spaces characters with `U+0020 SPACE`, c) replace all runs of space characters with a single `U+0020` space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cryptography algorithms process binary data, not text. So they take the string as a sequence of bytes and encrypt that. When you decrypt, you'll get the same sequence of bytes. If it was originally UTF-8 encoded, the result will also be UTF-8.

Even a binary-unsafe function like `crypt()` should be OK. Binary-unsafe functions generally only have a problem with strings that contain `0` bytes, because they make use of C functions that process null-terminated strings. UTF-8 encoding never includes `0` (unless the original string has an ASCII `NUL`), so it doesn't run into this problem.

Comment: What about the [crypt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function? It specifically says it is not (yet) binary safe! I have [trouble understanding what that exactly means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264514/in-php-what-does-it-mean-by-a-function-being-binary-safe)? It's also confusion that that function implies encryption yet does hashing. It's not always easy for non-English speakers to get all the nuances. I'm sorry, you might regard this comment as unrelated to your answer or the question.

Comment: As explained in your linked question, the issue is mainly embedded 0 bytes. UTF-8 never does that, so it's not an issue.

Comment: OK, thank you. In that case I agree with your answer. It's what I thought as well, but I wasn't a 100% sure. 

Comment: I've updated the answer to include this.